# Ng Build vs gulp build Angular 7

Tags: build, gulp, angular7

In my angular project I integrated gulp.
I would like to get the same result as ng build with gulp. I created the necessary tasks I can compile everything in the main.js file but if I deploy on a nginx server it gives me an error.
My gulpfile.js (task, compile)

```
gulp.task('compile', function () {


var tsResult = gulp.src('src/app/**/*.ts')
   .pipe(tsProject());


return tsResult.js
   .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
   .pipe(concat('main.js'))
   .pipe(sourcemaps.write(".")) 
   .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
```

});

My tsconfig

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "target": "ES5",
     "module": "es2015",
     "sourceMap": true,
     "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
     "experimentalDecorators": true,
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "removeComments": false
   }

 }
```